# CSS selector for floats that have wrapped to the nth line

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-float

Let's say I have a `<div>` with 10 floating elements inside:

```
<div>
  <div class=floatme>...</div>
  <div class=floatme>...</div>
  ...(8 more)
</div>
```

Depending on the horizontal space available, some of them will wrap to consecutive lines.

**Q**: How can I, say, style the ones on the second line?

```
<style>
  .floatme {
    float: left;
  }
  .floatme:if-wrapped-to-nth-line(2) {
    background: url("rainbows.png");
  }
</style>
```

```css
.app {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #bbb;
  animation: 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate woosh;
}

.app, button {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.tabs {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #039;
}
.tabs button {
  background: #039;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.toolbar {
  background: white;
}
.toolbar > div {
  padding: 3px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 2px solid #bbb;
}
.toolbar > .right {
  float: right;
  border-right: 0;
}
.toolbar button {
  border: 2px solid #777;
}
.toolbar button:hover {
  background: #bbb;
}
.toolbar::after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

@keyframes woosh {
  from {
    width: 300px;
  }
  to {
    width: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=app>
  <nav class=tabs>
    <button>Tab 1</button>
  </nav>
  <nav class=toolbar>
    <div>
      <button>A</button>
      <button>B</button>
    </div>
    <div class=right>
      <button>Right</button>
      <button>side</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>C</button>
      Description
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>D</button>
      <button>E</button>
      <button>F</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Q</strong>: How to style second line?
      <button>G</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>H</button>
      <button>I</button>
      Etc etc...
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I have some bad news, you can't.

Comment: There is NO CSS property / selector that can select / detect when a row has wrapped.... **none**!

Comment: Do all divs all have the same size?

Comment: with the informations you provided, you CANNOT

Comment: @RMo, No the divs' sizes depend on their content (which varies)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I have added a code snippet showing more complete `HTML` and the wrapping in action.

Answer (score -5):

You can give the element class name and don't try using `nth-child()` a lot because it's bad performance.

```
<div>
  <div class=floatme one>...</div>
  <div class=floatme two>...</div>
  ...(8 more)
</div>
```

Also you can use same idea to create gallery image using CSS Grid layout and BEM methodology.

CSS Grid Layout:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV8B24rSN5o&t=930s

BEM:
https://www.toptal.com/css/introduction-to-bem-methodology.

Comment: @Temani Afif Yes I think you want give ones div special style like image or background color, That is correct?

Comment: it's not my question, by read it again please before posting answers

Comment: Great, this problem say you have 8 or more div floating horizontal and some of them will wrap to consecutive lines. beside that you want special style ones on second line. So we can't using nth-child in this way because we have 8 or more div. So the best solution in the problem using Grid Layout and BEM.